# class or classes?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I am reading [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)
and find this sentence:

> In several places an Inventor and Inventor’s Society class are used as the target objects for expression evaluation.

Should the word `class` be `classes`?

Comment: Assuming that there is one Inventor class and one Inventor's Society class, I would rather change it to "In several places an Inventor class and an Inventor's Society class are used ..."  (The way it's written invites you to start out thinking that there is a single class called "Inventor and Inventor's Society".)

Comment: Apparently, the reference is to "Inventor" and inventor's "Society" class -- only "Society" is a class.

Comment: @Hellion but  in `... are used as the target objects`,both `are` and `objects` are plurals

Comment: @尤慕李 Yes, because there are two objects (one Inventor object and one Inventor's Society object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word should be class. Even though it is followed by 'are', class is not what makes the sentence plural. Because the subject has two parts, 'Inventor' and 'Inventor’s Society class', the sentence is plural and requires 'are'; since the author is talking about both.